# Failed to find the sum of the even elements of the array, and a strange error message

Tags: c++, arrays, function, compiler-errors

Our professor asked us to make 4 functions.
One to print the array, find the max value, min value,
and the sum of the even elements of an array.

My code was working, until I coded the evenSum function.
And this error message appeared:

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream’} and ‘void’)

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//print array
void print(int ar[4])
{
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    cout<<ar[i]<<'\t';
    cout<<endl;
}

// return the max value 
int maxValue(int ar[4])
{
    cout<<"Array max value: ";
    int max= ar[0];
    for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
    if(ar[i]>max)
    max= ar[i];
    return max;
}

// return the min value 
int minValue(int ar[4])
{
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Array min value: ";
    int min= ar[0];
    for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
    if(ar[i]<min)
    min= ar[i];
    return min;
}
// the sum of the even elements
void evenSum(int ar[4])
{
    cout<<endl<<"The sum of even elements: ";
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    if(i%2==0)
    sum+= ar[i];
    cout<<sum;
}


int main()
{
    int ar[4]={1,2,3,4};
    
    print(ar);
    cout<< maxValue(ar);
    cout<< minValue(ar);
    cout<< evenSum(ar);
    
}
```

I expected the code to give me the sum of the even elements,
and I don't quite understand the error message or how to fix it.

Comment: Design tip: those functions do too many things. Write a function that **finds** the largest value and returns it; in `main` call that function and show the value that it returns. Same for the others: they shouldn't be writing anything out.

Comment: The function **does** calculate the sum of the even elements, and if `main` just called it all would be more or less okay. But `main` calls the function and inserts the result into `std::cout` and that doesn't work because the function returns `void`, so there's nothing to insert. Change its return type to `int` and return `sum` at the end of the function. And, as I suggested in another comment, get rid of the output statements inside the functions.

Comment: You're printing the result of `evenSum` which you declared as returning `void`. Your suffering C++ compiler has no idea how to print a `void`. That's the reason for the error message.

Comment: C++ has moved on a lot and your teacher hasn't moved with the times.
Show him this, modern C++ is much better at describing what should be done instead of mucking about with pointers and "C" style arrays. Which tend to be very buggy and should not be taught in beginner classes (they might have a use in datastructures but even then usually new/delete and "C" style arrays are no longer necessary).  Example : https://onlinegdb.com/V7e87Krsh. Then C++ has [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) etc...

Comment: Oh and stop using `using namespace std` your teacher should also not teach you that.  So to summarize the C++ you are being taught is not the C++ we use in industry.

Answer (score 0):

void : is a lonely type, with no associated values to hang with him, except for a few cases, most commonly as a return type
of void function.

you put him with << and ostream,
although he love to stand a lone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).